# Why are Stratton Oakmont employees making fun of Steve Madden?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wolf-of-wall-street

In The Wolf of Wall Street (2013), Steve Madden came to put shares of his shoe company to institutional investors through Jordan's stockbroker company called Stratton Oakmont. Actually Steve Madden is the first IPO for Stratton Oakmont.

But Stratton Oakmont made fun of him by throwing shoes on him:

[image]

Why are Stratton Oakmont employees making fun of Steve Madden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Stratton Oakmont are a rowdy, uncouth bunch of man-children who represent the modern, corporate version of Lord of the Flies. Steve Madden was famous for designing shoes. And, not the toxic masculinity hunter culture that Stratton Oakmont represented. That was their way of welcoming/hazing what they considered to be a beta male.

Heaven knows what they would have thrown at the owner of Fredrick’s of Hollywood. Some athlete, athletic equipment manufacturer, car/motorcycle builder, or firearms producer might have gotten a similar, yet more respectful, greeting. Just as boisterous without the fear of getting pelted with products. And, Hugh Hefner’s or Larry Flint’s welcome would have been legen...(wait for it)...dary.